# error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have looked at other posts regarding the same, but i don't follow what mistake i must be doing.
I have the same name declared in Entity for the class as well as in Database declaration file too.
I'm also passing the same type of parameter as the entity class name, and still i'm getting this error thrown and it is not compiling. 
Here's my code. TIA

```
 @Entity(tableName = "current_task_table")
  data class CurrentTask (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val uid: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "task_name") val taskName: String
)

@Dao
interface CurrentTaskDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM current_task_table")
    fun getAllCurrentTask(): LiveData<List<CurrentTask>>

    @Insert
    suspend fun insertCurrentTask(currentTask: CurrentTask)

    @Query("DELETE FROM current_task_table")
    fun deleteAllCurrentTasks()
}

@Database(entities = [CurrentTask::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract val currentTaskDao: CurrentTaskDao

    companion object {

        @Volatile
        private var instance: AppDatabase? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): AppDatabase? {
            if (instance == null) {
                synchronized(this) {
                    instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                        context.applicationContext,
                        AppDatabase::class.java, "app_database"
                    )
                        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                        .build()
                }
            }
            return instance
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48015280/type-of-the-parameter-must-be-a-class-annotated-with-entity-while-creating-ge

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya changing my interface to abstract class did not work either, could you explain why i should be doing that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fixed it by removing `suspend` from DAO

> You cannot use suspend methods for DAO. Suspend function processed in compile time and compiler changes the signature of this function (different return type, an additional argument for state machine callback) to make it non-blocking.
> Room waits for particular method signature to generate code. So, until Room doesn't support coroutines directly, you cannot use suspend function for DAO.

Found my answer here:
[Error with Room dao class when using Kotlin coroutines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48694449/error-with-room-dao-class-when-using-kotlin-coroutines)

Answer (score 2):

Removing the suspend is not necessary.
I solve this problem by this link.
[Non-identification @Entity annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69589298/10090030)

You need only have a small change in your build.gradle
please change this line

```
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room"
```

to this:

```
annotationProcessor  "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room"
```

You can use suspend form in your DAO by this way