# Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with@Entity or a collection/array of it.kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<?super kotlin.Unit>$completion)

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

The whole error is :

```
error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it.
    kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super kotlin.Unit> $completion);
```

I don't know why I am getting this error. I am not able to perform database operations.  I know that this question is already asked by someone but the solution on that question is not working for me

**Favs.kt:**

```
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey

@Entity(tableName = "favourites")
data class Favs(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int = 0,
    val name_food: String,
    val rating_food: String,
    val cost_for_one: String,
    val image_url_food: String
)
```

**FavDao.kt:**

```
import androidx.room.Dao
import androidx.room.Delete
import androidx.room.Insert
import androidx.room.OnConflictStrategy
import androidx.room.Query
import com.aashushaikh.internshalamodule2.model.Foods

@Dao
interface FavDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertFav(fav: Favs)

    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteFav(fav: Favs)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM favourites")
    fun getAllFav(): List<Favs>

}
```

**FavDatabase:**

```
import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.Room
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase

@Database(entities = [Favs::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class FavDatabase(): RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getFavDao(): FavDao

    companion object{
        private var INSTANCE: FavDatabase? = null
        private val LOCK = Any()

        operator fun invoke(context: Context) = INSTANCE?:
        synchronized(LOCK){
            INSTANCE ?:
            createDatabase(context).also{
                INSTANCE = it
            }
        }

        private fun createDatabase(context: Context): FavDatabase{
            return Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext, FavDatabase::class.java, "note_db").build()
        }

    }
}
```

**FavRepository:**

```
class FavRepository(val db: FavDatabase){
    private val dao = db.getFavDao()

    suspend fun insertFav(fav: Favs) = dao.insertFav(fav)

    suspend fun deleteFav(fav: Favs) = dao.deleteFav(fav)
    
    fun getAllFav() = dao.getAllFav()

}
```

This is the **ViewModel:**

```
import android.app.Application
import androidx.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import com.aashushaikh.internshalamodule2.database.FavRepository
import com.aashushaikh.internshalamodule2.database.Favs
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class FavViewModel(val app: Application, val favRepository: FavRepository): AndroidViewModel(app) {
    fun addFav(favs: Favs) = viewModelScope.launch{
        favRepository.insertFav(favs)
    }

    fun deleteFav(favs: Favs) = viewModelScope.launch{
        favRepository.deleteFav(favs)
    }

    fun getAllFav() = favRepository.getAllFav()
}
```

This is how I am initialising:

```
private fun setUpViewModel() {
        val favRepository = FavRepository(FavDatabase(this))
        val viewModelProviderFactory = FavViewModelFactory(application, favRepository)
        favViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelProviderFactory)[FavViewModel::class.java]
    }
```

This is how I am using it:

```
override fun onItemClicked(item: Foods) {
        Toast.makeText(activity as Context, "Clicked on ${item.name}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        val fav = Favs(item.name, item.cost_for_one, item.rating, item.image_url)
        favViewModel.addFav(fav)
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62301115/error-type-of-the-parameter-must-be-a-class-annotated-with-entity-or-a-collect)

Comment: Nope. It doesnt work. I mean what will happen if I remove suspend from it?. I am getting this error in this project only. because in my other projects where I have used Room, coroutines and MVVM , I am not getting error

Answer (score 0):

Just Add this to solve the problem of room database:

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.0"
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.5.0"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.0"
implementation "androidx.room:room-testing:2.5.1"
```