# Getting Error in building the project using Dao interface and room library

Tags: android, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, dao, suspend

I am stuck with this issue since couple of days. I have gone through many threads where people faced similar issues but did not find any work around on this.
Im getting the error because of using suspend in dao interface but when i remove the error goes away but the app crashes when i try to open it after installation.
I have tried changing the version of room in gradle but that didnot work either.
have a look at my code.
The error message

```
 kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super kotlin.Unit> continuation);
```

NotesDao.kt

```
package com.example.notes

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.room.*

@Dao
interface NoteDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE) 
    suspend fun insert(note : Note)

    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(note : Note)

    @Query("Select * from notes_table order by id ASC")
    fun getAllNotes() : LiveData <List<Note>>
   
}
```

NotesRCAdapter.kt

```
package com.example.notes
import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class NotesRVAdapter(private val context: Context, private val listner : INotesRVAdapter)
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<NotesRVAdapter.NoteViewHolder>() {

    val allNotes = arrayListOf<Note>()
     class NoteViewHolder (itemview : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemview){
        val textView = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvNote)
        val deleteButton = itemview.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.ivDelete)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): NoteViewHolder {
        val viewHolder = NoteViewHolder( LayoutInflater.from(context)
            .inflate(R.layout.item_note, parent, false))
        viewHolder.deleteButton.setOnClickListener{
            listner.onItemClicked(allNotes[viewHolder.adapterPosition])
        }
        return viewHolder
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NoteViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentNote = allNotes[position]
        holder.textView.text = currentNote.text
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return allNotes.size
    }
    fun updateList(newList : List<Note>){
        allNotes.clear()
        allNotes.addAll(newList)

        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}

interface INotesRVAdapter{
    fun onItemClicked(note: Note)
}
```

NotesDataBase.kt

```
package com.example.notes

import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.Room
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase

@Database(entities = [Note::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class NoteDataBase: RoomDatabase() { 

    abstract fun getNoteDao(): NoteDao

    companion object {
        // Singleton prevents multiple instances of database opening at the
        // same time.
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: NoteDataBase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): NoteDataBase {
            // if the INSTANCE is not null, then return it,
            // if it is, then create the database
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    NoteDataBase::class.java,
                    "note_database"
                ).build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                // return instance
                instance
            }
        }
    }
}
//after this we will create our repository
```

NotesRepository.kt

```
package com.example.notes

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData

class NoteRepository(private val noteDao: NoteDao) {

    val allNotes : LiveData<List<Note>> = noteDao.getAllNotes()

    suspend fun insert(note: Note) {
        noteDao.insert(note)
    }
     suspend fun delete(note: Note){
         noteDao.delete(note)
     }
}
```

NoteViewModel.kt

```
package com.example.notes

import android.app.Application
import androidx.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class NoteViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application){
     private val repository : NoteRepository
    val allNotes : LiveData<List<Note>>
    init {
        val dao = NoteDataBase.getDatabase(application).getNoteDao()
        repository = NoteRepository(dao)
        allNotes = repository.allNotes
    }
    fun deleteNote(note: Note) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.delete(note)
    }
    fun insertNote(note: Note) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.insert(note)
    }
}
```

Note.kt

```
package com.example.notes

import androidx.room.ColumnInfo
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey

@Entity(tableName = "notes_table") /
class Note(@ColumnInfo(name = "text")val text: String) { 
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id = 0
}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.notes

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), INotesRVAdapter {
    lateinit var viewModel: NoteViewModel
    private val input = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etInput)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val RecyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView)
        RecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        val adapter = NotesRVAdapter(this, this)
        RecyclerView.adapter = adapter

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this,
            ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(application))
            .get(NoteViewModel::class.java)
        viewModel.allNotes.observe(this, Observer { list ->
            list?.let {
                adapter.updateList(it)
            }
        })
    }
    override fun onItemClicked(note: Note) {
        viewModel.deleteNote(note)
        Toast.makeText(this,"${note.text} Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

    fun submitData(view: View) {
        val noteText = input.text.toString()
        if (noteText.isNotEmpty()){
            viewModel.insertNote(Note(noteText))
            Toast.makeText(this,"$noteText Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}
```

immediate help will be appreciated in understanding the issue and where I went wrong.
Thanks.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48694449/error-with-room-dao-class-when-using-kotlin-coroutines)

Comment: Actually I already referred to this thread and implemented the suggestions
Yet it didn't work for me :'(

Answer (score -1):

Try changing class of entity to data class and also the id field

```
package com.example.notes

import androidx.room.ColumnInfo
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey

@Entity(tableName = "notes_table") 
data class Note(
@ColumnInfo(name = "text")val text: 
 String), 
 @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) 
 @ColumnInfo(name = "text_id")
 var id = 0)
```

Comment: I tried this but the same problem exists. I guess It is not related to data class but the use of coroutine and suspend function return type in dao interface.

Comment: Can you show complete error? And if possible the stack trace.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p4NHu4CG1Vq6S1H5IrhkYtXHNWbzjsjo/view?usp=sharing
This is the link for the problems that came up, I am really stuck with this issue with three of my projects
I hope anybody enlightens me

Comment: Something wrong in your Gradle build. Update your dependencies.

Comment: As I assumed ,I tried to run your code and there is no error related to use of suspend function in dao but got error in the line     private val input = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etInput) which I fixed by moving it inside onCreate method. I am able to run your code w/o error. So update your dependencies.

Comment: Hi, can you share the gradle dependencies so that I can compare and also what is the version of your android studio?
and my gradle dependencies were uptodate when I last compiled the code and uploaded here? so if you share your gradle code then I will be able to compare. You can check the image link of my dependencies : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mVMN4fk-8zhKXS-Hnp7g0qemaijPW3ai/view?usp=sharing

Comment: implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"

    // To use Kotlin annotation processing tool (kapt)
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"       
 room version is 2.4.3 with apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
 Android Studio Chipmunk, Gardle version = 7.3.3, kotlin version =1.7.10

Comment: Thanks, means a lot. changing the dependency version like you suggested worked for me. Now I am sure the error was due to the version.