# Why can't I use suspend modifier in dao's @Insert in room database?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sqlite, android-room, android-database

When I use the `@Insert` function in `DAO`, the following error occurs.

```
error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it.
```

All other codes using Room use suspend in @Insert, so I don't know the cause of the error.

Then I just deleted suspend and it works normally.

For what reason?

---

**gradle**

```
def room_version = "2.4.2"

implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
```

**Entity**

```
@Entity
data class DailyWorkout(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id : Int = 0,
    val date: String,
    val bodyPart: String, // bodyPart
)
```

**DAO**

```
@Dao
interface WorkoutDao {
    @Query("SELECT * From WorkoutList")
    fun getWorkoutList() : List<WorkoutList>

    @Insert
    fun insertDailyLog(dailyWorkout: DailyWorkout)
}
```

**Repostiory**

```
class WorkoutListRepository(private val dao: WorkoutDao) {

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    fun createDailyLog(part: BodyPart) {
        val date = LocalDate.now()
        val formatter =
            DateTimeFormatter
                .ofPattern("yyyy/M/dd E")
                .format(date)

        val data = DailyWorkout(date = formatter, bodyPart = part.getPart())
        dao.insertDailyLog(data)
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
class WorkoutListViewModel(
    private val repository: WorkoutListRepository

) : ViewModel() {
    private var _list = MutableLiveData<List<String>>()
    val list: LiveData<List<String>>
        get() = _list

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    fun createDailyLog(part: BodyPart) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repository.createDailyLog(part)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the entity class tho

Comment: entity code is updated

Comment: Have you added [Database](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room#database)?

Comment: @Mr.Techie of course. Without the suspend modifier, it works fine.

Comment: @ybybyb strange...without `suspend` you would be blocking the main thread, which is not okay. Have you read [this article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/room-coroutines-422b786dc4c5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating the gradle dependencies:

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.0-alpha02"
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.5.0-alpha02"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.0-alpha02"
```

Comment: it does work. however what is the cause?

Comment: If I remember correctly, this was a recurring bug in room

Comment: You can find more about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48738350/15749574

Comment: Also, if that solved your problem, please mark my answer as a solution (or just delete the question cause it pretty much is a duplicate)

Comment: From room version 2.1 onwards the support for coroutines is present, so that linked answer may not work..

Comment: @Mr.Techie check out the end of the linked response ;)

Comment: @JustSightseeing please see the link that I have provided at the very last of my answer

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your room dependencies in your app level `build.gradle` to:

```
plugins {
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.3")
    annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.3")

    kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.3")

    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:2.4.3")

}
```

Then you can use the `suspend` modifier in your `DAO`

```
@Dao
interface WorkoutDao {
    @Query("SELECT * From WorkoutList")
    suspend fun getWorkoutList() : List<WorkoutList>

    @Insert
    suspend fun insertDailyLog(dailyWorkout: DailyWorkout)
}
```

Don't forget to add `suspend` modifier to function that call these above `suspend` functions. In your case the **Repository** should be

```
class WorkoutListRepository(private val dao: WorkoutDao) {

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    suspend fun createDailyLog(part: BodyPart) {
        val date = LocalDate.now()
        val formatter =
            DateTimeFormatter
                .ofPattern("yyyy/M/dd E")
                .format(date)

        val data = DailyWorkout(date = formatter, bodyPart = part.getPart())
        dao.insertDailyLog(data)
    }
}
```

For more details: read [this article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/room-coroutines-422b786dc4c5).