# "Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time." error on my Coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

My Coroutine is running on the main thread, which i've specified in my Coroutine context:

```
class ClickPreference(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : Preference(context, attrs), CoroutineScope, View.OnClickListener {

    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.Main

override fun onClick(v: View?) {
    when (key){
        "logout" -> {
            CoroutineScope(coroutineContext).launch {
                CustomApplication.database?.clearAllTables()
                Log.d("MapFragment", "Cleared Tables")
            }
            if (Profile.getCurrentProfile() != null) LoginManager.getInstance().logOut()
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
            val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
            context.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm still getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
```

on my above Coroutine call `CustomApplication.database?.clearAllTables()` to my `Room` database.

Here is my `CustomApplication`:

```
class CustomApplication : Application() {

    companion object {
        var database: AppDatabase? = null
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        CustomApplication.database = Room.databaseBuilder(this, AppDatabase::class.java, "AppDatabase").build()
    }
```

Why am I still getting the error if my coroutine context runs on the main thread?

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44167111/android-room-simple-select-query-cannot-access-database-on-the-main-thread

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error says that it should NOT run on the main thread. Database operations (and every other form of IO) can take a long time and should be run in the background.

You should use `Dispatchers.IO` which is designed for running IO operations.

Comment: Thanks. What about query operations such as `@Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM matched_users WHERE :matchId = match_id LIMIT 1")` - would that use `Dispatchers.IO`? It's not input/output as it's only querying the DB.

Comment: Any DB call you make should be called from IO thread instead of Main thread which is very precious thing for Android from user perspectives.

Comment: It is now possible to mark DAO functions as suspend functions. Then you don’t need to use Dispatchers.IO to call it. This is a cleaner solution than having to wrap blocking calls in the top level of your coroutine.

Comment: It's not just possible, it recommended.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `Dispatchers.Main` for the long-running task. You have to use `Dispatchers.IO` for database operations, look likes:

```
class ClickPreference(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : Preference(context, attrs), CoroutineScope, View.OnClickListener {



override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.IO

override fun onClick(v: View?) {
    when (key){
        "logout" -> {
            CoroutineScope(coroutineContext).launch {
                CustomApplication.database?.clearAllTables()
                Log.d("MapFragment", "Cleared Tables")
                if (Profile.getCurrentProfile() != null) LoginManager.getInstance().logOut()
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
            }

            val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
            context.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What about query operations such as @Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM matched_users WHERE :matchId = match_id LIMIT 1") - would that use Dispatchers.IO? It's not input/output as it's only querying the DB.

Comment: Database query basically reads from DB file like file reading, so obviously it should be IO operation.

Answer (score -6):

> Hi, this problem is because the database must run on mainthread.
> Because of this you have to add this line of code to the database
> section

```
Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
            DataBaseTextChat.class, Constants.DB_TEXT_CHAT)
            .allowMainThreadQueries()
            .addCallback(roomCallBack).build();
```

Comment: It is NOT a correct solution! Be responsible and thoughtful programmer and don't use it!

Comment: It is not a correct solution as it blocks the UI thread if your query takes enough time which results in ANR.