# Error when updating an item in Room database

Tags: kotlin, android-room, android-jetpack-compose

When I update an item it says `Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.`
The app uses Jetpack compose.
I have a function in my DAO used to update an item

```
@Update
fun update(item:Item)
```

And a repository to access the database

```
fun update(item:Item){
    itemDao.update(item)
}
```

In my viewmodel, I use viewModelScope to call the function

```
fun update(item: Item){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            itemRepository.update(item)
        }
    }
```

However, when I call `itemViewModel.update(item)` in an `onclick()` scope, the error still occurs which I dont know why.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57657741/cannot-access-database-on-the-main-thread-since-it-may-potentially-lock-the-ui?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: shouldn't your `update()` function in your DAO be a suspend function? I mean, even if called from a coroutine scope, `viewModelScope` is tied to the main thread. Maybe explicitly declaring `update()` as a suspend function could help.

Comment: Yes. The top answer on the linked question is outdated in the sense that it doesn’t mention this preferable solution of marking the function suspend.

Comment: Making it suspend indeed worked. Anyway, maybe it was a bug in the Android Studio that when I wrote it as suspend, it said that the qualifier was redundant which was why I then removed it.