# Dao Room database no access

Tags: java, android

So I've made this database, and for some reasone I get an error message: `Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.` 
The log says that the error is in: `wordList = (ArrayList<Note>) wDb.noteDao().getAllNotes();`, but I can't see what I did wrong?

**ListActivity.java**

```java
    private NoteDatabase wDb;
    ArrayList<Note> wordList;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        s1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.PL);//Kald denne først
        startService(new Intent(ListActivity.this,WordLeanerService.class).putExtra("inputExtra", s1));
        setupConnectionToWLservice();

        LoadData(); //Load SharedPreferences
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        s2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.DC);
        s3 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.DC2);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        Exit = findViewById(R.id.CloseApp);
        editSearch = findViewById(R.id.EditText);
        searchBtn = findViewById(R.id.search_button);
        getData(); //get set data from EditActivity and set Arrays

        wDb = NoteDatabase.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        wordList = (ArrayList<Note>) wDb.noteDao().getAllNotes();
        if(wordList.isEmpty()){
            for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                Note nWord = new Note(s1[i], s3[i], s2[i], images[i], items[i], Notes[i]);
                wDb.noteDao().insert(nWord);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Note.java**

```java
package com.example.word_learner_app;

import androidx.room.ColumnInfo;
import androidx.room.Entity;
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey;

@Entity(tableName = "note_table")
public class Note {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "wordTitle")
    private String title;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "description")
    private String description;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "prounciation")
    private String prounciation;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "image")
    private int Image;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "rating")
    private String rating;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "notes")
    private String notes;

    public Note(String title, String description, String prounciation, int Image, String rating, String notes) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.prounciation = prounciation;
        this.Image = Image;
        this.rating = rating;
        this.notes = notes;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public String getProunciation() {
        return prounciation;
    }

    public int getImage() {
        return Image;
    }

    public String getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public String getNotes() {
        return notes;
    }
}
```

**NoteDao.java**

```java
package com.example.word_learner_app;

import androidx.room.Dao;
import androidx.room.Delete;
import androidx.room.Insert;
import androidx.room.Query;
import androidx.room.Update;

import java.util.List;

@Dao
public interface NoteDao {
    @Insert
    void insert(Note note);

    @Update
    void update(Note note);

    @Delete
    void delete(Note note);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM note_table")
    List<Note> getAllNotes();
}
```

**NoteDatabase.java**

```java
package com.example.word_learner_app;

import android.content.Context;

import androidx.room.Database;
import androidx.room.Room;
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase;

@Database(entities = {Note.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class NoteDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    private static NoteDatabase instance;

    public abstract NoteDao noteDao();

    public static synchronized NoteDatabase getInstance(Context contexte){
        if(instance == null){
            instance = Room.databaseBuilder(contexte.getApplicationContext(),
                    NoteDatabase.class, "note_database")
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .build();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

**Logcat**

```
2020-03-27 16:40:06.697 18007-18007/? E/ord_learner_ap: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2020-03-27 16:40:08.226 18007-18007/com.example.word_learner_app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.word_learner_app, PID: 18007
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.word_learner_app/com.example.word_learner_app.ListActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotMainThread(RoomDatabase.java:267)
        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.java:323)
        at androidx.room.util.DBUtil.query(DBUtil.java:83)
        at com.example.word_learner_app.NoteDao_Impl.getAllNotes(NoteDao_Impl.java:158)
        at com.example.word_learner_app.ListActivity.onCreate(ListActivity.java:67)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: The error message is pretty straightforward: do not do database I/O on the main application thread. If you wish to keep your DAO as it is, call your DAO methods on a background thread. If you are willing to change your DAO, consider using `LiveData` or RxJava, which will cause Room to arrange to do your database I/O on background threads. Long-term, as Biscuit suggests, you might consider coroutines if/when you start programming in Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is unauthorised in Android, you're trying to fetch data in the database from the `MainThread` which can cause a freeze of the application. That's why it is advise to use `Coroutines` to do such functions.

EDIT: In java you can use [callback](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase.Callback.html) as in this [codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/)

Comment: The code in the question is in Java, not Kotlin, so coroutines is not an available short-term option.

Answer (score 0):

Use `allowMainThreadQueries()` to allow main thread queries for room by default the flag is `false` else u need to insert in back ground thread.

So to insert data synchornously use this with the builder.

```
instance = Room.databaseBuilder(contexte.getApplicationContext(),
                    NoteDatabase.class, "note_database")
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .allowMainThreadQueries() // this allows u to build in main thread
                    .build();
```

**Edit**

But as @CommonsWare suggested try to use background thread to insert probably using `Rx` / `Executors` / `AsyncTasks` for Kotlin you can use `Coroutines`.
As main thread insertion might freeze the UI

Also @See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44167111/android-room-simple-select-query-cannot-access-database-on-the-main-thread)

Comment: This is not a very good idea. Freezing the UI to perform database I/O results in user-visible jank, particularly on low-end devices, or with lots of data, or with complex database operations.

Comment: `AsyncTask` in your link are being deprecated

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform your actions in the background thread. publish your results to UI thread

- You achieve this using Async task/Rx java/Kotlin Coroutines

It's not recommended run DB operations in the main thread but you can access to the database on the main thread with allowMainThreadQueries()

```
MyApp.database =  Room.databaseBuilder(this, AppDatabase::class.java, "MyDatabase").allowMainThreadQueries().build()
```

Comment: `allowMainThreadQueries()` is not a very good idea. Freezing the UI to perform database I/O results in user-visible jank, particularly on low-end devices, or with lots of data, or with complex database operations.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the Room database in the main thread, and that is why you got `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.`.

Whenever you do an operation that has nondeterministic or long time, you must do it in a Worker (background) thread instead of the main thread.

There are several ways to do a background thread, such as [`AsyncTask`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask), and [`Executors`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html).

**Note**: `AsyncTask` is deprecated as of android R.

In your provided code you did access to the database a couple of times (getting all the notes and inserting notes into database), so I am going to fix them with [Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html), specifically with [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

Also you may consider [`LiveData`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) for returning back database list asynchronously where it handles all the background thread for free.

`LoadNoteListListener` is created to be triggered whenever the list is returned back from database, so it's time now to handler the list in your main thread with its `onNotesListLoaded()` callback.

```
class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoadNoteListListener {

    private NoteDatabase wDb;
    ArrayList<Note> wordList;

    private static Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(); // to run DB access operations in background thread

    // Listen when the list of notes are returned back from Room database
    public interface LoadNoteListListener {
        void onNotesListLoaded(ArrayList<Note> notes);
    }


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        s1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.PL);//Kald denne først
        startService(new Intent(ListActivity.this,WordLeanerService.class).putExtra("inputExtra", s1));
        setupConnectionToWLservice();

        LoadData(); //Load SharedPreferences
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        s2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.DC);
        s3 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.DC2);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        Exit = findViewById(R.id.CloseApp);
        editSearch = findViewById(R.id.EditText);
        searchBtn = findViewById(R.id.search_button);
        getData(); //get set data from EditActivity and set Arrays

        wDb = NoteDatabase.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

        getAllNotes(this);

    }



    public void getAllNotes(LoadNoteListListener listener) {
        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                listener.onNotesListLoaded((ArrayList<Note>) wDb.noteDao().getAllNotes());
            }
        });
    }



    @Override
    void onNotesListLoaded(ArrayList<Note> notes) {
        wordList = notes;
        if(wordList.isEmpty()){
            for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                Note nWord = new Note(s1[i], s3[i], s2[i], images[i], items[i], Notes[i]);
                insertNote(nWord);
            }
        }       
    }


    public void insertNote(Note note) {
        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                wDb.noteDao().insertNote(note);
            }
        });
    }

    ....
}
```