# How to return a single object from room database?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-room

As this [document](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Query) tells:

[image]

So I've returned a object TaskStat from the database(all tables in database are created successfully). My Dao is:

> Dao.class

```java
    @Query("SELECT * FROM task_statistics WHERE owner_ID = :ownerId")
    TaskStat getTaskStatOf(long ownerId);
```

Then I've called the `getTaskStaOf()` method from `Repository class` and further from `ViewModel class`. Here is the code for Repository & ViewModel:

> Repository

```java
public TaskStat getTaskStatOf(Task task) {
        return taskDao.getTaskStatOf(task.getTaskId());
    }
```

> ViewModel.class

```java
if (task.getProgress() == task.getMaxProgress()) {
                TaskStat taskStat = taskRepository.getTaskStatOf(task);
                taskStat.setStatus(true);
                taskRepository.updateStat(taskStat);
            }
```

But when I reach the first line of `if()` condition in ViewModel the app crushes.. Log says:

```java
at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotMainThread(RoomDatabase.java:267)
        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.java:323)
        at androidx.room.util.DBUtil.query(DBUtil.java:83)
        at taskHelper.TaskDao_Impl.getTaskStatOf(TaskDao_Impl.java:276)
        at taskHelper.TaskRepository.getTaskStatOf(TaskRepository.java:86)
        at taskHelper.TaskViewModel.incrementProgress(TaskViewModel.java:46)
        at com.example.mohasaba.MainActivity$2.onItemLongClick(MainActivity.java:71)
        at taskHelper.TaskAdapter$TaskHolder$2.onLongClick(TaskAdapter.java:113)
        at android.view.View.performLongClickInternal(View.java:7205)
        at android.view.View.performLongClick(View.java:7163)
        at android.view.View.performLongClick(View.java:7181)
        at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:27294)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

I'm confused where I'm doing wrong! Can you help me?

Comment: This error tells that Room doesn't allow to interact with Sqlite (both queries and changes) on Main Thread. You should switch all these operations on another thread. There are many answers about that on SO, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44167111/android-room-simple-select-query-cannot-access-database-on-the-main-thread) one of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this. In the ViewModel class change this lines:

```java
if (task.getProgress() == task.getMaxProgress()) {
                TaskStat taskStat = taskRepository.getTaskStatOf(task);
                taskStat.setStatus(true);
                taskRepository.updateStat(taskStat);
            }
```

to:

```java
if (task.getProgress() == task.getMaxProgress()) {
                    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            TaskStat taskStat = taskRepository.getTaskStatOf(task);
                            taskStat.setStatus(true);
                            taskRepository.updateStat(taskStat);
                        }
                    });
                    thread.start();
                }
```

Hope this will work.