# App is crashing On inserting data in RoomDb

Tags: java, android, android-room

I am trying to insert data in RoomDb but at the the time of data insertion app is crashing even if I am writing insertion operation in thread.I have a recycler view adapter class in which I have a click listener based on that I want to add data in RoomDb.

Here is my logcat error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
```

Below is my code:

**ProductAdapter.class**

```
public class ProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.ViewHolder> {

List<Product> productList;
Context context;

public ProductAdapter(List<Product> productList, Context context) {
    this.productList = productList;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.product_row,parent,false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Product product = productList.get(position);

    holder.productName.setText(product.getName());
    holder.productPrice.setText(product.getPrice());
    Glide.with(context).load(product.getProduct_image()).placeholder(R.color.teal_200).into(holder.productImage);

    holder.productCard.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,R.anim.recycler_anim));

    holder.addToCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.tick.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.addToCart.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            ((AppCompatActivity)context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ProductDb db = ProductDb.getInstance(context);
                    CartProduct  cartProduct = new CartProduct(product.get_id(),product.getName(),product.getProduct_image(),
                                               product.getPrice(),"1");
                    db.productDao().insert(cartProduct);
                }
            });
         }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return productList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView productImage,addToCart,tick;
    TextView productName,productPrice;
    CardView productCard;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        productImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.productImage);
        productName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.productName);
        productPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.productPrice);
        productCard = itemView.findViewById(R.id.productCard);
        tick = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tick);
        addToCart = itemView.findViewById(R.id.addToCart);
    }
  }
}
```

How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Room - simple select query - Cannot access database on the main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44167111/android-room-simple-select-query-cannot-access-database-on-the-main-thread)

Comment: the point of getting a stack trace is to identify the cause of the exception. once you have the exception, you can do research on that, so try to find others who have had exactly that same problem, in this case, the problem you're facing has occurred numerous times, so you should be able to find a solution without having to ask the same question again

Comment: `even if I am writing insertion operation in thread` -> `.runOnUiThread` -> `Cannot access database on the main thread `

Answer (score 1):

This exception is thrown when you try to access the database on main thread without declaring `allowMainThreadQueries()` in database builder.
if you want to access database on main thread then construct your database object like following
`Room.databaseBuilder(App.getInstance().getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, DB_NAME).allowMainThreadQueries()`

But that is not recommended. Use async task or any other background thread for database operations to have a smooth user experience

Updates:

Async task is deprected. you can check more alternatives to async task on [this](https://medium.com/code-yoga/some-great-alternatives-for-asynctasks-e8113747673a)

A sample code that i use for database operations with RxJava is

```
Single.fromCallable(new Callable<Long>() {
        @Override
        public Long call() throws Exception {
            return getProductDao().insert(product);
        }
    }).observeOn(Threads.ui())
            .delaySubscription(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .subscribeOn(Threads.io())
            .subscribe(new RxGenListener<Long>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Long aLong) {
                    listener.onCallback(aLong);
                }
            });
```

Comment: async tasks are deprecated

Comment: I use RxJava for this. Schedulers.io etc

Comment: exactly, you shouldn't recommend it in an answer to others though

Comment: OK Thanks. I am updating the answer

Comment: @BilalBangash,could you please tell how to do it using RxJava