# How to call Room database function in a thread when that function need to return a value in android

Tags: android, android-room

I have created a Room database and i am trying to implement the following functions

```
public int getRowCountSenderHelper()
    {
         return senderHelperDao.checkRowCount();
    }

    public SenderHelper getOneChat()
    {
        return senderHelperDao.getOneChat();
    }
```

Now the android is giving me this error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
```

Now i cannot use AsyncTask since they are deprecated and i cant call `senderHelper.getOneChat()` and `senderHelperDao.checkRowCount()` in a Thread because it need to return a value and i fear then when new thread goes to work in background the main thread may return empty value.

Any way to tackle this problem will be appreciated

Comment: Some useful workarounds can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58767733/android-asynctask-api-deprecating-in-android-11-what-are-the-alternatives).

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44167111/android-room-simple-select-query-cannot-access-database-on-the-main-thread

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Room - simple select query - Cannot access database on the main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44167111/android-room-simple-select-query-cannot-access-database-on-the-main-thread)

Comment: @Max no the nature of question is different. The question you suggest ask about query not working while mine has some other problem.

Comment: @live-love asyncTask is deprecated. In the document it says its deprecated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Define a variable of type LiveData and make a getter method for it.

2- make return that variable.

3-use getter to get the value of LiveData from your activity.