# Dao Database, check in room record exists (Cannot access database)

Tags: java, android

How to correctly check if a record exists? In my case I get the error message.

```
In Fragment:
GroupDao groupDao = AppDatabase.getInstance(requireContext()).groupDao();

if (groupDao.isGroupExists(0)) {
 //
}

GroupDao:
@Query("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM group_table WHERE id = :groupId)")
    Boolean isGroupExists(Integer groupId);
```

```
Error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
```

Comment: What do you think the exception message means?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Room - simple select query - Cannot access database on the main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44167111/android-room-simple-select-query-cannot-access-database-on-the-main-thread)

Comment: You cannot run any database query or a network request on UI thread. Try reading the error message a bit more carefully next time, that is pretty self explanatory here

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to make the query on the UI thread, add allowMainThreadQueries() on AppDatabase get.

```
fun get(context: Context): AppDatabase? {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized(AppDatabase::class) {
                INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext,
                        AppDatabase::class.java, "database.db")
                        .allowMainThreadQueries()
                        .build()
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check error message.

`Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.`