# Android Room - Cannot access database on the main thread

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, android-threading

I'm getting the "Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time." error, but from what I understand I'm launching a new coroutine to insert the data to the database. What am I doing wrong?

RadioActivity:

```
        val finishButton : Button = findViewById(R.id.radioFinishButton)
        finishButton.setOnClickListener {
            val radioName = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.radioName)
            val radioUri = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.radioUri)
            val replyIntent = Intent()

            when {
                TextUtils.isEmpty(radioName.text) -> radioName.error = "Radio name is required!"
                TextUtils.isEmpty(radioUri.text) -> radioUri.error = "Radio URL is required!"
                else -> {
                    replyIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_REPLY_NAME, radioName.text.toString())
                    replyIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_REPLY_URI, radioUri.text.toString())
                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, replyIntent)
                    finish()
                }
            }
        }
```

RadioFragment:

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val getResult = registerForActivityResult(
            ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
        ){
            var name = ""
            var uri = ""
            if(it.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                it.data?.getStringExtra(RadioActivity.EXTRA_REPLY_NAME)?.let{ reply ->
                    name = reply
                }
                it.data?.getStringExtra(RadioActivity.EXTRA_REPLY_URI)?.let{ reply ->
                    uri = reply
                }
                Toast.makeText(context, "Name = ${name}, uri = ${uri}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                val radio = Radio(5, name, uri)
                radioViewModel.insert(radio)
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error while saving", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }

        val recyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.radioRecyclerView)
        val adapter = RadioListAdapter()
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)

        radioViewModel.radioList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            it.let{
                adapter.submitList(it)
            }
        }
    }
```

RadioRepository:

```
val radioList: Flow<List<Radio>> = radioDao.getAll()
    @Suppress("RedundantSuspendModifier")
    @WorkerThread
    suspend fun insert(radio: Radio) {
        radioDao.insert(radio)
    }
```

RadioModel:

```
    fun insert(radio: Radio) = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.insert(radio)
    }
```

Comment: Hi Kuba, please check the answers of this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/44167111/15262615

Comment: Could you please provide code for `RadioViewModel`. I guess you are launching a coroutine there, right?

Comment: `from what I understand I'm launching a new coroutine` - from what I see there is no coroutine at all in posted code. you should call `insert` inside some scope or some other `Thread`

Comment: Sorry about that, I've included the part where I run `insert` method inside ViewModel scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to switch context in `RadioRepository`:

```
suspend fun insert(radio: Radio) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    radioDao.insert(radio)
}
```

You are using `@Suppress("RedundantSuspendModifier")` annotation, which suppresses the `RedundantSuspendModifier` error. This error means your `insert` function is non `suspend` and will be running in thread, which invoked it.

`withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` switches the context of coroutine, making `insert` function to run in background(worker) thread.

Comment: That was it, thank you. I was sure using @WorkerThread annotation would be enough for it to work

Comment: No, `@WorkerThread` annotation doesn't make function to run on a worker thread, it only denotes that method should only be called on a worker thread.

Answer (score 1):

Try to specify the dispatcher on your viewmodelScope

```
fun insert(radio: Radio) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    repository.insert(radio)
}
```

if it doesn't work, try to switch context by using `withContext`

```
fun insert(radio: Radio) = viewModelScope.launch {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.insert(radio)
    }
}
```